How to handle before and after update event subscribers in typeorm for bulk update?
In my project i have task entity. When a field of task is updated after and before update EventSubscriber will be triggered  which is working fine for a single task update.
When i tried to bulk update the tasks before and after update EventSubscriber is not functioning as expected.
How to handle event subscribers for bulk update?
I tried to bulk update 100 records, before and after update subscribers are not handling the records as expected.before update is taking one taks details and comparing it with multiple tasks in after update which results in undesired behaviour.
